# ResolvePackageNotFound error while trying to create an environment of anaconda

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, anaconda3

I am trying to create an environment based on the instruction

```
conda env create -f environment.yml
```

the output is

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - opencv==4.5.1=py36ha15d459_1
  - tornado==6.1=py36h2bbff1b_0
  - setuptools==52.0.0=py36haa95532_0
  - six==1.15.0=py36haa95532_0
  - m2w64-libwinpthread-git==5.0.0.4634.697f757=2
  - importlib-metadata==3.7.3=py36haa95532_1
  - py-opencv==4.5.1=py36hfacbf0b_1
  - zeromq==4.3.4=hd77b12b_0
  - wincertstore==0.2=py36h7fe50ca_0
  - libclang==11.1.0=default_h5c34c98_1
  - pywinpty==0.5.7=py36_0
  - pyqt-impl==5.12.3=py36he2d232f_7
  - vc==14.2=h21ff451_1
  - winpty==0.4.3=4
  - m2w64-gmp==6.1.0=2
  - prompt_toolkit==1.0.15=py36h60b8f86_0
  - sqlite==3.35.1=h2bbff1b_0
  - statsmodels==0.12.2=py36h2bbff1b_0
  - libpng==1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - mkl-service==2.3.0=py36h779f372_2
  - msys2-conda-epoch==20160418=1
  - pywin32==300=py36h68aa20f_0
  - icc_rt==2019.0.0=h0cc432a_1
  - freetype==2.10.4=hd328e21_0
  - pandoc==2.12=haa95532_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libs-core==5.3.0=7
  - xz==5.2.5=h8cc25b3_1
  - mkl==2020.4=hb70f87d_311
  - scipy==1.5.2=py36h7ff6e69_2
  - pyqt5-sip==4.19.18=py36he2d232f_7
  - tk==8.6.10=he774522_0
  - vs2015_runtime==14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - libprotobuf==3.15.8=h7755175_1
  - libwebp-base==1.2.0=h2bbff1b_0
  - libtiff==4.2.0=h763f289_2
  - pandas==1.1.5=py36hd77b12b_0
  - pyqtwebengine==5.12.1=py36he2d232f_7
  - icu==68.1=h6c2663c_0
  - terminado==0.9.2=py36haa95532_0
  - pip==21.0.1=py36haa95532_0
  - python==3.6.13=h3758d61_0
  - matplotlib==3.3.4=py36haa95532_0
  - certifi==2020.12.5=py36haa95532_0
  - pyrsistent==0.17.3=py36he774522_0
  - m2w64-gcc-libgfortran==5.3.0=6
  - markupsafe==1.1.1=py36he774522_0
  - argon2-cffi==20.1.0=py36h2bbff1b_1
  - traitlets==4.3.3=py36haa95532_0
  - pyqt==5.12.3=py36ha15d459_7
  - pillow==8.1.2=py36h4fa10fc_0
  - numpy==1.19.5=py36h4b40d73_2
  - m2w64-gcc-libs==5.3.0=7
  - mistune==0.8.4=py36he774522_0
  - matplotlib-base==3.3.4=py36h49ac443_0
  - cffi==1.14.5=py36hcd4344a_0
  - freeglut==3.2.1=h0e60522_2
  - jupyter_core==4.7.1=py36haa95532_0
  - openssl==1.1.1j=h2bbff1b_0
  - pyqtchart==5.12=py36he2d232f_7
  - cycler==0.10.0=py36haa95532_0
  - libopencv==4.5.1=py36h568d6e9_1
  - pyzmq==22.0.3=py36h1d5d788_1
  - scikit-learn==0.24.1=py36hf11a4ad_0
  - notebook==6.2.0=py36haa95532_0
  - kiwisolver==1.3.1=py36hd77b12b_0
  - ca-certificates==2020.12.5=h5b45459_0
  - lcms2==2.12=h83e58a3_0
  - zlib==1.2.11=vc14h1cdd9ab_1
  - jpeg==9d=h2bbff1b_0
  - intel-openmp==2020.3=h57928b3_311
  - ipykernel==5.5.0=py36h7b2dad6_1
  - zstd==1.4.9=h19a0ad4_0
  - libsodium==1.0.18=h62dcd97_0
  - lz4-c==1.9.3=h2bbff1b_1
  - qt==5.12.9=h5909a2a_4
  - jasper==2.0.14=hea7d32e_2
```

I am using macbook air m1

could anyone help to solve the problem ?

I've tried to do the same on windows and it worked successfuly.
on my macbook it doesn't work, tried to search for a solution and install anaconda again and still it fails

Comment: Often a given package version is only available on certain OSes. Try unpinning some of the versions, or adding other conda channels.